# Declare variable with return value of a future

Tags: flutter, dart

This may be a silly question but my Problem is, that I have a return value of a future and I want to assign a variable to it, but the variable stays the same only in the "code-block"

And I want to return the value synchronous

```
bool getDarkMode() {
    bool testBool;

    test().then((myBool) {
      testBool = myBool;
    });
    return testBool;
  }
```

I want to return the value of the `testBool` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `then` implies, that `test()` returns a Future. This means you cannot use it a synchronous manner. (Assuming `test` to have the following signature: `Future<bool> test() { ... }`

You would need to make your function `getDarkMode` to by async as well like this:

```dart
Future<bool> getDarkMode() {
  return test();
}
```

or if you need to process the result of `test`:

```dart
Future<bool> getDarkMode() async {
  bool res = await test();
  return res;
}
```

There is no way to "convert" an async value to a sync one.

If you need this value in a build method of a widget, you can use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: getDarkMode(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text('Loading...');
      }
      final darkMode = snapshot.data;
      return Text(darkMode ? 'DARK' : 'LIGHT');
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is it the one and only way? Because I used  this method in a lot of classes in synchronous way.

Comment: Your first code isn't correct. There needs to be `await`

Comment: why would it need an `await`? I can directly return a `Future` without awaiting in the current method. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Can you explain this please.

Comment: could you specify what you do not understand?

Comment: Is it possible to return the myBool variable in synchronous way? And if yes, how?

Comment: no. If `test()` returns a Future there is *no way* to return it in a synchronous way.

Comment: Ok, you helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<bool> getDarkMode() async {
  bool testBool = await test();
  return testBool;
}
```

OR you can eliminate the `testBool` and use

```
Future<bool> getDarkMode() async{
  return await test();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to return a synchronous value. Is this possible?

Comment: The code you posted, I just wrote it using `Future`, so you are getting same value you had earlier.